# Could I put my app on router memory for my ios clients to download it?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have 3 files

*.html
`<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://my ip add/hotspot/manifest.plist/" class="aaa">link </a>`

*.plist
*.api

my plist file is perfectly match with the samples that I seen on internet ....

and my api is a tested app and downloadable file in app store ...

and I am sure about my html codes

My question is : How could I upload my files on my router that everyone in my wireless network could download it??!!!!!

Comment: You can't put files on a router (unless it supports file sharing and you connect an external hard drive to it). You need some kind of physical server (a Raspberry Pi is perfect for this), install a web server like apache2, then put the file on it. Or you get webspace from a website like 000webhost.com and put the file there. Or you use the Public folder of Dropbox.

Comment: Your app has to be signed for [Enterprise distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shallowThought says in their comment, you can't deliever apps from your own storage unless they are signed for Enterprise distribution, which requires you to join Apple's enterprise developer program. If you do that then yes, you could deliver your app from a local file server.

Comment: I have another links on my router for other Operation Systems they work perfect ....

Comment: I searched on internet a lot and create that 3 files do I need to write another kind of code???

Comment: Apple only allows apps that are properly digitally signed to be installed on their devices. Normally you must get the app from the app store. If you join the enterprise program it's possible to do an over-the-air installation. You'll need to search on "iOS Enterprise over-the-air installation" The process is quite complicated and fussy.

Comment: "I... create that 3 files..." I have no idea what that means. If you don't have an enterprise developer account you can't install apps onto an iPhone from "router memory", no matter what "kind of code" you write. It's not a question of code, it's a question of having an app that has the correct digital signatures, which must be generated using a valid Apple Enterprise developer account.

Comment: I dont have 99$ to create an account just for one local network!!!!! Thats too much for me is there a free way????

Comment: No, there is no free way.